# Unable to boot to Windows after cloning with Clonezilla

Tags: windows-7, boot, installation, iso-image

I purchased a laptop that came with Windows 7 preinstalled. According to a number of folks, the OS is no longer distributed as a image on disc; rather its provided as an image on the hard drive.

I want to use Windows 7 on another machine, so I cloned the first partition onto a thumb drive using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). I then went to the machine I want to run Windows 7 on and used Conezilla to write the image. I've been using Clonezilla for years, so I'm fairly certain I did everything that was required.

At the Windows 7 machine after reboot to the local hard drive, I'm getting a *Non-system disc error or disk error*. I also tried to boot directly to the thumb drive, but it resulted in the same problem.

I don't ever recall having this much trouble when installing an OS from the CD or DVD, so I feel like I am missing obvious (or some folks were wrong about the OS image being a partition on the hard drive).

Why am I having trouble installing Windows 7? What am I missing?

Comment: Gparted and mark the partition as bootable?

Comment: You should have cloned all partitions, sometimes W7 depends on a different partition to start the boot process.

Comment: @acejavelin - oh, good point. I actually have Gparted in the drive. Let me take a look around.

Comment: Moab is right... Win7 usually has 2 partition, a "boot" and OS partition.

Comment: @Moab - thanks, I was not aware of that. I might need two of the three partitions I saw under Clonezilla.

Comment: I *wish* Clonezilla allowed me to clone partitions 1 and 3 as a set. All of this will fit on on 8 GB thumb drive...

Comment: I use Acronis, make an image of all partitions, then when I restore the image I can pick which partitions i want to restore to the new drive.